# Google Cloud Load Balancer http-to-https forwarding not working with forms that contain passwords

Tags: css, fastapi, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-load-balancer, http-redirect

I'm using the Google Load-Balancer with Cloud run where my webapp runs in a container and I configured the Load Balancer according to the manual where http can be forwarded to https and the https Load-Balancer is configured properly with the ssl certificate. My webapp runs with fastAPI. It is a very simple ToDo webapp from a tutorial.

Everything seems to work fine. When I type in my webpage `http://example.com` I get forwarded to `https://example.com`.

Now the strange part I'm not figuring out. I have a simple login page. The login page contains a form with a username, a password and a submit button:

(the layout contains the boostrap ui. I also tried semantic ui, with the same result)

```html
{% include 'layout.html' %}

<div style="margin-top: 100px;" class="ui container">
  <div class="ui card">
    <div class="content">
      <div class="header">
        Login
      </div>
      <div class="description">

        {% if msg %}
        {% if msg == 'Logout Successful' or msg == 'User successfully created' %}
        <div class="ui positive message">
          <div class="header">Success</div>
          <p>{{msg}}</p>
        </div>
        {% else %}
        <div class="ui negative message">
          <div class="header">Error</div>
          <p>{{msg}}</p>
        </div>
        {% endif %}
        {% endif %}

        <form class="ui form" method="POST" action="/auth">
          <div class="field">
            <label>Username</label>
            <input type="text" name="email" required>
          </div>
          <div class="field">
            <label>Password</label>
            <input type="password" name="password" required>
          </div>
          <button class="ui primary button" type="submit">Login</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="extra content">
      <a href="register">Register?</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My endpoint in my fastAPI app is:

```py
@router.post("/", response_class=HTMLResponse)
async def login(request: Request, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    try:
        form = LoginForm(request)
        await form.create_oauth_form()

        url = todos_router.url_path_for("home")
        response = RedirectResponse(url=url, status_code=status.HTTP_302_FOUND)

        validate_user_cookie = await login_for_access_token(response=response, form_data=form, db=db)

        if not validate_user_cookie:
            msg = "Incorrect Username or Password"
            return templates.TemplateResponse("login.html", {"request": request, "msg": msg})
        return response
    except HTTPException:
        msg = "Unknown Error"
        return templates.TemplateResponse("login.html", {"request": request, "msg": msg})
```

When I type-in a username and password I get the following "error" from the browser (Edge/Chrome):

[image: connection not secure]

[image: example.com]

**BUT** for some reason I can prevent this from happening by changing the type of the password field from

```html
<div class="field">
<label>Password</label>
<input type="password" name="password" required>
</div>
```

to

```html
<div class="field">
<label>Password</label>
<input type="text" name="password" required>
</div>
```

But of course I don't want to have a plain text field for the password. How can I fix this? Has anyone experienced this issue? Why is it possible to submit a form without an error when I don't use a password field?

Comment: Look at your last screenshot. Notice the title bar. The web browser is using HTTP instead of HTTPS. Make sure that redirection to HTTPS is working correctly. The best choice is to make the entire site redirect to HTTPS.

Answer (score 0):

That seems to be actually normal. Since you have a field of type `password` you're about to insert sensitive information (i.e. your password). The browser is telling you that the site is not secure.

Now, I'm entirely sure if it's because you're sending the information to a non `HTTPS` website or if it's a problem with the certificate. You've obscured the website name, so it's difficoult to tell.